# Feedback from Apple: app crash, but i can't find the carch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

I received an App Submission Feedback from Apple:

> We found your app crashed on launch so we were unable to review it.
>
> Please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure it will
>   launch without crashing, and that it runs as expected, before
>   resubmitting.
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

**However, I'm unable to find the crash reason.**

**The apple log:**

```
Incident Identifier: 9264F39E-DF25-404C-A378-E27B8D349D8C

CrashReporter Key:   dd4a401e71e6af348859f1d7f6a15bf4fa31a51b

Hardware Model:      xxx

Process:             Spas [185]

Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/AE3BD0DE-CD1B-4493-B108-76E447401135/Spas.app/Spas

Version:             1.1.0 (1.1.0)

Code Type:           ARM (Native)

Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-12-02 11:49:35.794 -0800

Launch Time:         2014-12-02 11:49:29.235 -0800

OS Version:          iOS 8.1.1 (12B435)

Report Version:      105


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Triggered by Thread:  0


Last Exception Backtrace:

(0x2556449f 0x33128c8b 0x255643e5 0x28de4229 0x28d03303 0x28b42805 0x28a26af9 0x28a26a7d 0x28a2c953 0x28a2a3bd 0x28a9460d 0x1297bd 0x28a914f1 0x28c8643f 0x28c8898b 0x28c93209 0x28c87217 0x2bc9b0d1 0x2552ad7d 0x2552a041 0x255287c3 0x254763c1 0x254761d3 0x28a8b1bf 0x28a85fa1 0x18f9d3 0x336a8aaf)


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3376edfc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x337ecd33 pthread_kill + 59
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3370e905 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32a4a9c5 abort_message + 85
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32a6466d default_terminate_handler() + 265
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33128f23 _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32a61de1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32a618ab __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33128dcf objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                  0x25476459 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 629
10  CoreFoundation                  0x254761cf CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  UIKit                           0x28a8b1bb -[UIApplication _run] + 555
12  UIKit                           0x28a85f9d UIApplicationMain + 1437
13  Spas                            0x0018f9cf main + 67
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x336a8aad start + 1
```

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log they've sent you.

Comment: run your app on release mode. Change your Build Configuration settinng via Edit Scheme->Build Configuration, Debug to Release. Then run application. Probably you will get the crash

Comment: it not get the crash

Comment: Apple using `OS Version:          iOS 8.1.1`. Run your app under 8.1.1, surely it will crash...

Answer (score 1):

Run your application in iOS 8.1.1 (build 12B435) device through Xcode in release mode.

It should show you the crash.